# C basic memory management implementation

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management

I am trying to write a basic memory management system to a C library project in a GCC environment, and came here to ask if what I am doing is permitted or advisable by C standards.

Basically, my code base is huge, and contains many required and non-required malloc operations inside the code. It's not that I am so careless to put malloc everywhere I wanted, but I didn't have the information about which values were necessary until the nearing end of the project.

Basically my plan is to create a **global** reference counter that is shared between translation units. And write a malloc wrapper that increments and adds to this reference count, and store the pointers inside. So what remains is to free all the references in a loop at the end of the run time. I activate this at the very end of the run time, so reference lifetime is not a issue for me to track, therefore somewhat makes the problem easier.

I also need to ask this important question. I have many types of pointers in the code. So when reference counting, I have to store these as `void*`, will this cause undefined behavior and create an issue ?

**Edit:** `These` values that I refer to being stored as `void*` are regular pointers that allocated with malloc (could be char*, int*, struct* etc...), and used inside the code. However given that the reference counter will not know the types of these, so I plan to keep them in a list of `void*`.

As to the OS clean-up suggestion, unfortunately, I am creating a large library base rather than an executable, so even though my code ends running, I should free the memory so the library user won't have problems (the user's code does not end after it calls my library functions, that why I cannot depend on OS clean-up)

**Edit2:** Let's create a small example of what I am planning to do.

```
int ref_count = 0;
void* ref_list[64]; // 64 is arbitrary.

void* mallocWrapper(size_t size){
    void* result = malloc(size);
    ref_list[ref_count] = result;
    ref_count += 1;
    return result;
}
```

Then use this list to free all the allocated memory in the code.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @SouravGhosh **What I am doing is permitted or advisable by C standards ?** and the `void*` question. I think it's very clear, I am starting to think some people write these comments automatically.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly are you doing? You are storing _these_ as `void*`, what are "these"? You are storing "types of pointers" in a `void*` variable? Or storing the reference count in the `void*` variable? You want to implement something like `void **pointers; size_t cnt; void *__wrap_malloc(size_t size) { pointers = realloc(pointers, sizeof(*pointers) * ++cnt); return pointers[cnt-1] = malloc(size); }` ?

Comment: Are you sure that your environment requires to free all memory resources at the _end of the runtime_? Usually the OS cleans up the process with all memory resources allocated.

Comment: @MaxPaython Exactly - what are you doing? Sorry, I'm still not clear.

Comment: Let me clarify in an edit.

Comment: It would be nice if you created a [mre] showing what you had in mind

Comment: So you are asking if storing pointers to different types of variables in elements of a `void *` array is undefined behavior? For example if  `void *array[5]; char c; int i; array[0] = &c; array[1] = &i;` is undefined behavior? It would really help if you would implement it first.

Comment: @KamilCuk Please check the edit.

Comment: How huge is your codebase ? If you are creating a library that leaks memory everywhere, please reconsider. You will need to replace all your malloc with your implementation yourself, I think it is best that you instead fix your memory allocations.

Comment: @Tic Indeed.  Having to write additional code to paper over symptoms from other problems is a serious [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).  Fix the root cause - the leaking of memory. The currently-posted example is likely to introduce even more problems. For one, it's not multithread-safe at all.  It also appears pointless - the only safe time to free the memory the array refers to is right before the process exits, making the freeing of memory effectively pointless on must platforms.

Comment: With this kind of implementation, you can only free everything at the end of the process. It is generally too late. If you have one function in your library API that a user can call multiple times, you will leak and the program will crash before you get to free your mess. If your library needs to handle tasks in parallel (multithreaded), you'll also be in a really bad spot.
EDIT: @Andrew Henle Exactly, I've add to work with some horrible library with a function that free all the library memory, please never ever do that. I ended up just throwing it and writing the thing myself.

Comment: @Tic The user can call the function multiple times, however the result from that first call is processed and never used again (of course freed after processing). So it prevents build-up while the user's process continues.

Comment: @MaxPaython Then why do you need this kind of allocator if you are already freeing correctly between calls ? Do you have some kind of static malloc'd data in your library ?

Comment: The scent of XY is very strong here

Comment: Sounds like "use valgrind" to me (see https://valgrind.org/ ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a valid way to do it. `malloc()` returns just a pointer, it doesn't know about types at all, just chunks of memory.

Note, if you `free()` stuff in your library, you will have to write a `freeWrapper()` too, or you will end up freeing some things twice.

Comment: Well, *that* struggle is over, nobody won, everybody lost ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/relicensing-content-under-cc-by-sa